# Exchange Particles for IMF

Tags: virtual-particles, bosons, quantum-chemistry

Quantum field theory describes forces as being mediated by a field (e.g. gluon field for strong force, electromagnetic field for electromagnetic force). These are often modeled as a mediating boson particle (gluon, photon). However, in the case of the strong nuclear force, because of color confinement, gluons do not directly mediate the force, but instead pions do. I assume that because there is no confinement for the electromagnetic force, photons would still be the 'mediating particle' for intermolecular forces like van der Waals forces, but I was wondering if that assumption is correct, and if there is any situation where there could be a mediating particle like a pion for molecular level forces. (I am aware that the mediating particle is just a model, and simply curious if there was any molecular analog that could model IMFs as a particle exchange).